# When is pre-provisioned VolumeSnapshot useful in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, snapshot, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I'm reading the Kubernetes documentation of `VolumeSnapshot` and `VolumeSnapshotContent` at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/. However, I was a little bit confused when I was reading the part of "pre-provisioned snapshots".

I can see that the resource `VolumeSnapshot` is created by the user, and it is the administrator's responsibility to create the corresponding `VolumeSnapshotContent`. In the "dynamically provisioned snapshots" scenario, a `VolumeSnapshotContent` will be automatically created right after a `VolumeSnapshot` is created with `VolumeSnapshotClass`, which was pre-configured by administrators. It makes sense to me.

However, in the scenario of "pre-provisioned snapshots", it seems that administrator has to create `VolumeSnapshotContent` before the user requests a snapshot with a `VolumeSnapshot` resource. In this case, I don't see how it's possible for the administrator to create a `VolumeSnapshotContent`. Which volume should be taken the snapshot? When should the snapshot be taken? These information should come from the user request, and there's no way that the administrator would know in advance. Therefore, the administrator can never create pre-provisioned snapshots.

I must have missed something. I appreciate if you can correct me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a misunderstanding, "pre-provisioned" does not mean VolumeSnapshotContent is created before the snapshot request. Rather that the snapshot content was provisioned before registering the VolumeSnapshotContent into kubernetes

Later on, in the "binding" section, doc says:

> In the case of pre-provisioned binding, the VolumeSnapshot will remain unbound until the requested VolumeSnapshotContent object is created.

End-user creates their VolumeSnapshot. Then admin proceeds with snapshotting data, and eventually registers a VSC and binds it to end-user's VolumeSnapshot.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. To make sure, do you mean that VolumeSnapshot object will always be created before the creation of VolumeSnapshotContent object, in both "pre-provisioned" or "dynamically provisioned" snapshot scenarios?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: I wonder what the prefix of "pre-" mean in "pre-provisioned". Originally I thought it means "VolumeSnapshotContent created before VolumeSnapshot", but it looks like it's not the case. Would you mind giving me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: I would assume it means you pre-provisioned the snapshot, on the backend storage, before creating the object.

Comment: Excuse me, I got another question: when creating a VolumeSnapshot in pre-provisioned mode, we'll have to fill in a required field: volumeSnapshotContentName. How do we know the name of the underlying VolumeSnapshotContent when it's not created yet?

Comment: Following my previous question: in pre-provisioned mode, it looks like we don't put the information of which volume to take the snapshot in the VolumeSnapshot object. Then, how do the administrator know which volume do the user want to take the snapshot?

Comment: After reading the documentation again, I started to think that VolumeSnapshot is not created before VolumeSnapshotContent in the "pre-provisioned" scenario.

The documentation says "A cluster administrator creates a number of VolumeSnapshotContents. They carry the details of the real volume snapshot on the storage system which is available for use by cluster users. They exist in the Kubernetes API and are available for consumption."

It looks like VolumeSnapshotContents are created before user wants to take any snapshot. What do you think?

Comment: 1) You bind your VS to your VSC when registering the VSC.
2) The VS object DOES reference which volume you want to take a snapshot from
3) "[VolumeSnapshotContents] carry the details of the real volume snapshot on the storage system which is available for use by cluster users" very much suggests snapshot was taken already, at that stage. You create your VSC, when you know where it's stored. .

Comment: 1) Got it, thanks. 2) How can a VS object reference which volume to take snapshot from? I didn't see any field other than "volumeSnapshotContentName" in the example at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/#volumesnapshots 3) The statement "[VolumeSnapshotContents] exist in the Kubernetes API and are available for consumption." seems VSC are created before the creation of VS, if the word "consumption" means "users create VS to consume the existing VSC".

Comment: 2) You're right, it's the other way around, the VSC references the VS. 3) I think that consumption means you can use that snapshot creating a new PVC. Next statement mentions VSC carry the details of the real volume snapshot on the storage system which is available for use.  Keeping in mind there are no controllers watching over those objects, as you are provisioning snapshots yourself, out of a storageclass that may not have dynamic provisioning: consume really means end-user is eventually going to ask you to init their PV out of some VS, you would/could use the VSC to resolve actual volume.

Comment: I created a PR against the Kubernetes documentation, to add a note for the pre-provisioned snapshot use case: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/36407. My PR was based on the assumption that VS is created before VSC. However, one of the Kubernetes developers said that it was not the case and left a comment in the PR. Therefore, I adopted the assumption of VSC will be created before VS and modified the PR. Now the PR was merged. Therefore, I think it's more common to see VSC created before VS.

Comment: Do you have any other comments?